# Put multiple functions into a single dplyr mutate across everything e.g. change mulitple different strings

Tags: r, function, dplyr, stringr

Example data:

```
df1 = data.frame(x1 = rep(c("foo", "bar"), 4),
                 x2 = rep(c("FOO", "fix", "broke", "fix"), 2))
```

I want to, for example, change multiple different strings, in this case change `foo` to `done` and `bar` to `open`. I am using `stringr` and `dplyr`. Is it possible to put more than one function after the `~` so that multiple functions are run across all columns in the same line of code, rather than as the example above where `across` and `everything` are repeated:

```
> df1%>%
+   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace(.,"(?i)bar", "open")),
+          across(everything(), ~ str_replace(., "(?i)foo", "done")))
    x1    x2
1 done  done
2 open   fix
3 done broke
4 open   fix
5 done  done
6 open   fix
7 done broke
8 open   fix
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the tidyverse way would be to chain multiple functions together using the pipe operator. This means you only need to call `across` once.

```r
df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace(.,"(?i)bar", "open") %>% 
                                 str_replace("(?i)foo", "done")))
    x1    x2
1 done  done
2 open   fix
3 done broke
4 open   fix
5 done  done
6 open   fix
7 done broke
8 open   fix
```

Comment: Great this works. Didn't consider pipe! Any idea why it goes wrong if `str_replace` changed to `gsub?`: `df1%>%  mutate(across(everything(), ~ gsub("bar", "open",.) %>%                                gsub("foo", "done",., ignore.case = T)))`

Comment: You might need to wrap each `gsub` call in curly brackets since the `.` is not the first argument, @MarkDavies

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may also use `str_replace_all` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %> 
    mutate(across(.fns = ~str_replace_all(., c("(?i)bar" = "open", "(?i)foo" = "done"))))

#    x1    x2
#1 done  done
#2 open   fix
#3 done broke
#4 open   fix
#5 done  done
#6 open   fix
#7 done broke
#8 open   fix
```